# Consultar a quantidade de pessoas por idade

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query

Como realiza a consulta para saber o total de pessoas na faixa de 0 a 5 anos de idade, sendo que se não tiver nenhuma criança com uma determinada idade, informe 0;

`select idade, count(*) as qtd from pessoa group by idade order by idade`

exemplo do problema atual

```
+-----------+--------+
|   idade   |   qtd  |
+-----------+--------+
|     0     |    3   |
+-----------+--------+ 
|     3     |    7   |
+-----------+--------+ 
|     5     |   11   |
+-----------+--------+
```

Exemplo de como eu preciso dos dados

```
+-----------+--------+
|   idade   |   qtd  |
+-----------+--------+
|     0     |    3   |
+-----------+--------+ 
|     1     |    0   |
+-----------+--------+ 
|     2     |    0   |
+-----------+--------+ 
|     3     |    7   |
+-----------+--------+ 
|     4     |    0   |
+-----------+--------+ 
|     5     |   11   |
+-----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o between para filtra o intervalo de idade que você quer.

```
create PROCEDURE BuscarTotalIdadePorFaixa
    @iniIdade int, 
    @fimIdade int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare  @pessoa table(idade int, qtd  int)
    declare  @pessoaAux table(idade int, qtd  int)


    insert into @pessoa values
    (0,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),
    (4,1),(5,1),(5,1),(5,1),(6,1),(6,1),(7,1),(8,1),(8,1),(8,1),(8,1)

    declare @Idade int = @iniIdade;

    while (@Idade <= @fimIdade)
    begin
        print @Idade
        insert into @pessoaAux values (@Idade , 0); 
        set @Idade = @Idade + 1;
    end

    select idade , 0 from @pessoaAux pAux
    where not exists (select idade from @pessoa P where P.idade = pAux.idade)
    union all
    select idade, count(*) as qtd 
    from @pessoa 
    group by idade 
    having  idade between @iniIdade and @fimIdade
    order by idade

END
```

Comment: Amigo, mas eu preciso que retorne 0 se nao existir pessoas com aquela idade, esse é o problema.

Comment: veja se resolve, essa solução foi feita em sql server, mas a ideia e a mesma para mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Como é um conjunto bem pequeno de idades que vai de zero a cinco anos, em ORACLE tem uma solução bastante interessante para você realizar isso com um comando chamado merge que simplesmente é: você tem uma tabela com dados zerados de qtde, variando idade de 0 a 5 e outra que só tem os dados de fato e para as idades que não existem, não tem registro (como no seu caso).

Talvez exista um comando similar no MySQL. Não conheço, mas pode ser que exista.

Veja que interessante:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_IDADES (
  IDADE NUMBER,
  QTDE NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TEMP_IDADES VALUES (0,0);
INSERT INTO TEMP_IDADES VALUES (1,0);
INSERT INTO TEMP_IDADES VALUES (2,0);
INSERT INTO TEMP_IDADES VALUES (3,0);
INSERT INTO TEMP_IDADES VALUES (4,0);
INSERT INTO TEMP_IDADES VALUES (5,0);

SELECT * FROM TEMP_IDADES;

-- nesta estao os dados reais
CREATE TABLE IDADES (
  IDADE NUMBER,
  QTDE NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO IDADES VALUES (4,30);
INSERT INTO IDADES VALUES (5,20);

SELECT * FROM IDADES;

-- MERGE DAS TABELAS COM AS SITUACOES ATUALIZA OU INSERE.


MERGE INTO TEMP_IDADES TEMPORARIA
   USING (SELECT IDADE, QTDE FROM IDADES) REAIS
   ON (TEMPORARIA.IDADE = REAIS.IDADE)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
      UPDATE SET TEMPORARIA.qtde = REAIS.qtde
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (TEMPORARIA.QTDE, TEMPORARIA.IDADE)
     VALUES (REAIS.QTDE,REAIS.IDADE);

SELECT * FROM TEMP_IDADES;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]